# Cannot browse to http://localhost:8000/shell/ and permissions don't appear to be respected

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have downloaded and installed AWS Explorer.  I have created a table as shown below:

[image]

I am able to connect to the table using this code:

```
var config = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig
                {
                    ServiceURL = "http://localhost:8000/"
                };
                client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(myAccessKeyID, mySecretAccessKey, config);
```

I have two issues:

1) I cannot browse to http://localhost:8000 in IE.  Should I be able to do this?

2) I have noticed that I can change the values of myAccessKeyID and mySecretAccessKey to any values and I can create a table in code.  However, the table does not appear in AWS Explorer.  Why can I create a table in code without the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should not, DynamoDb has no web interface listening at port 8000, so you should no able to browse it through IE.

2)I suppose you're using the AWS SDK, if so the client CreateTable() should return a response, what is this response TableStatus? It might not have been sucessfully created.

See this link for an example on how to create a table: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetTableOperationsExample.html